# ios - how to get id full array value from a UITableView cell?

Tags: ios, ios5, uitableview

I am able to get the text value of a cell like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    NSUInteger *row = [indexPath row];

    // NOW GET THE NAME AND ID FROM THAT ROW
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *cellText = cell.textLabel.text;    

    NSLog(cellText);    
}
```

but I need to be able to get the id of that item, or at least use the row to get the item from the array.

Here is how I get the array for the UITableView populated:

```
@synthesize items_array;
```

and later:

```
                 items_array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

                 [self.itemList reloadData];
```

and the array has JSON which has for every item, fields like item_id, and item_name

So when the user clicks on an item from the list, how can I get the id field?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a custom cell? Does it have an item_id property? That's how I would do it. Or you'll have to search the (2d?) array with the indexpath.row as the index

Comment: @mkral ah I see, so essentially, I have to put a custom object into the cell, correct? And just display one of the fields in the object in the uitableview?  Just out of curiosity, could you plese post some example code of how you do that.

Comment: Well runmad's answer will work, if you want to access the JSON data. And you're still going to need to use that for setting the `cell.fieldID` how are you creating the cells? Is the text based on some returned JSON value?

Comment: Creating a custom cell is probably bad in this case since you are not changing the view of the cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    NSDictionary *itemInfo = [items_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *itemID = [itemInfo objectForKey:@"item_id"];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *idField = [items_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `NSDictionary *info = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` then `NSString *idField = [data objectForKey:@"item_id"` depending on how the JSON is structured.

Comment: @runmad I got an error trying to do this NSLog(idField); after the line you suggest: "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Comment: try `NSLog(@"Class: %@", [[items_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] class]` I think it's of type dictionary, but I may be wrong

Comment: @mkral I tried your original suggestion of     NSDictionary *info = [items_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
    NSString *idField = [info objectForKey:@"item_id"];
    
    NSLog(idField); and nothing was output to the console :(

Comment: @mkral got it to work with your help! If you want you can post it as an answer and I will accept.  Thank you both Runmad and Mkral :) You guys rock for helping!

Comment: What did you change from my initial code (when it returned blank)? As far as answer, I submitted an edit for runmad's answer. Just accept his, it was close.

Comment: @mkral Once I got the variable names right to match my variable names, it worked like a charm :)  ...originally I had forgotten to change one.

Comment: OK great, looks like my edit got rejected? I'll add my answer below.